# PhpStorm and expanded php definitions

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-hinting

Using code hinting, PHPStorm can show me quick function definitions; can it be configured to show me more detailed examples of the function's use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can place the cursor (text-cursor, not mouse-cursor) on any PHP function and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (Menu: View -> External Documentation).

That will open the detailed description incl. examples and user-comments (read: the PHP manual).

Comment: Might it be different on a mac?

Comment: Probably. You can check in the menu: View -> External Documentation

Comment: Hmmmm...It does indicate shift + F1 should work, yet it's greyed out.  Is there another setting that will ungrey it?

Comment: If it's greyed out, the cursor (text-cursor, not mouse cursor) is not on a function that has PHP manual documentation.

Answer (score 0):

With an **OSX** specific keyboard, you may need to trigger the `F1` key by pressing `fn + F1`. So here are two use cases that work for me:

1. **Open php.net documentation:** `fn + shift + F1`
2. **Quick view php.net documentation:** `fn + F1`

You may also find it useful that you can enable Quick documentation on hover. Open up `File > Preferences`, navigate to the `Editor` section, and at the bottom check the box for *Show quick doc on mouse move*.