# PhpStorm and expanded php method definitions on same project

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

Using code navigation, PHPStorm can not show me quick function definitions; *can it be configured to show me more detailed examples of the function's use?* I have used <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> but its not helping.

Answer (score 0):

as from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959268/phpstorm-and-expanded-php-definitions)

You can place the cursor (text-cursor, not mouse-cursor) on any PHP function and press Shift + F1 (Menu: View -> External Documentation).

That will open the detailed description incl. examples and user-comments (read: the PHP manual).